# Passing associated function of type as parameter

Tags: function, rust, parameter-passing

I have an implementation of a type `Network` with the associated function `pub fn is_acyclic(&mut self) -> bool`. I am trying to create a generic function `fn run_test(n: usize, f: fn()->bool)` so I can pass functions of the same signature as `Network::is_acyclic` so I can apply these functions on constructed `Network`s `n` times.

See my code here:

```
#[test]
fn acyclic() {
    assert!(run_test(10, Network::is_acyclic))
}
...
fn run_test(n: usize, f: fn()->bool) -> bool {
    let mut results = vec![];
    for _ in 0..n {
        let (l,r) = gen_test_nets();
        let mut net = Network::new_random(l, r);
        results.push(net.f());
    }
    results.iter().all(|&x| x)
}
```

I am getting 2 errors in particular:

```
Mismatched Types ...
   = note: expected fn pointer 'fn(Network<_>) -> _'
                 found fn item 'for<'a> fn(&'a mut Network<Node<_>>) -> _ {Network::<Node<_>>::is_acyclic}'
```

Which I gather implies I am passing `Network::is_acyclic` wrong in the `acyclic` method. I have tried passing as `Network::is_acyclic()`, I had tried `Try` and `as` in various forms that I have found in similar questions online which I honestly didn't understand what I was doing. I also tried `where` keyword on the `run_test` definition which I think is supposed to coerce the parameter type into a function, though I don't believe that's the problem since it knows I am trying to have a function pointer as an argument (which is what I believe I want).

I have also tried this version of `run_test` method with the same results

```
fn run_test<T>(n: usize, f: fn(Network<T>)->bool) -> bool {
    let mut results = vec![];
    for _ in 0..n {
        let (l,r) = gen_test_nets();
        let mut net = Network::new_random(l, r);
        results.push(net.f());
    }
    results.iter().all(|&x| x)
}
```

In particular, `is_acyclic` is implement in `impl<T: Clone + PartialEq + Eq + Hash> Network<Node<T>>` and I have tried making all of these declarations in the test method with no luck. I get the same errors "expected function pointer, found function item" along with a few bonus errors along the lines of `associated type bindings are not allowed here... assert!(run_test::<T: Clone + PartialEq + Eq + Hash>(10, Network::is_acyclic))`.

The other error I am getting is `no method named 'f' found for struct 'Network' in the current scope` on the line `results.push(net.f());` in `run_test`. I am not sure if this error will resolve on its own once I have correctly passed a function pointer as `f` in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_acyclic` is not an "associated function", it's a method. This means that it takes a `self` parameter in some way. In your case, since it's part of a trait implementation for `Network<Node<T>>`, its prototype is equivalent to:

```
fn is_acyclic (self: &Network<Node<T>>) -> bool;
```

Given an instance `net` of type `Network<Node<T>>`, it is usually called with the [method call syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) `net.is_acyclic()`, but it can also be called with the [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls): `Network::<Node::<T>>::is_acyclic (&net)`. So in your case, this should work:

```
#[test]
fn acyclic() {
    // Need to replace the `?????` with the real type that `gen_test_nets`
    // and `Network::new_random` create.
    assert!(run_test(10, Network::<Node::<?????>>::is_acyclic))
}
...
fn run_test(n: usize, f: for<'a> fn (&'a Network<Node<?????>>) -> bool) -> bool {
    let mut results = vec![];
    for _ in 0..n {
        let (l,r) = gen_test_nets();
        // You can find out the real type of `net` with an IDE or:
        // let net: () = Network::new_random(l, r);
        // which will fail to compile and the error message will give
        // you the actual type.
        let mut net = Network::new_random(l, r);
        results.push(f (&net));
    }
    results.iter().all(|&x| x)
}
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but your code would be a lot more efficient like this:

```
fn run_test(n: usize, f: for<'a> fn (&'a Network<Node<?????>>) -> bool) -> bool {
    (0..n).all (|_| {
        let (l,r) = gen_test_nets();
        // You can find out the real type of `net` with an IDE or:
        // let net: () = Network::new_random(l, r);
        // which will fail to compile and the error message will give
        // you the actual type.
        let mut net = Network::new_random(l, r);
        f (&net)
    })
}
```

This version avoids allocating a temporary vector (and reallocating it as it grows), and returns as soon as one of the test returns `false` without wasting time doing the others.

Comment: Thank you for the definition clarifications re: method vs associated function. indeed I should have referred to the concrete type that `new_random` returns. Though, here you have parameter `f` as a type rather than as a function. I get the error on the call to `f` as `call expression requires function`.

Comment: @Karl sorry, copy-paste mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for showing me an efficiency improvement on my code! Unfortunatly I still get the error `note: expected fn pointer 'for<'a> fn(&'a Network<Node<String>>) -> _'
                 found fn item 'for<'a> fn(&'a mut Network<Node<String>>) -> _ {Network::<Node<String>>::is_acyclic}'` on the call to `run_test`

Comment: I've made a MWE that matches the structure of my code (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=864039566ba1e9fd3e496c1a865c7db9) and it compiles just fine. So I believe your answer is correct, I am hesitant to accept just yet until my local code is running. I will have to accept it soon, hopefully after I have found what my error is.

Comment: It was the a difference of mutability. Because `is_acyclic` implementation actually took a mutable reference, I needed to put that in my definition of `run_test`. All working now. Thanks for your help!